# Black screen on install (no OS installed) on a VIA P820 board

Tags: installation, boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I've read several posts about using -- nomodeset when trying to install.

The hardware is a [via P820](http://www.viaembedded.com/en/products/boards/productDetail.jsp?productLine=1&id=1050&tabs=1) board, that about it!

I have tried this without success.

1. Boot from CD or USB device
2. Select Language
3. F6 select nomodeset
4. ESC
5. remove 'quiet' and ensure '-- nomodeset' is at the end of the boot string.
6. Enter.
7. The CD or the USB device will flicker with activity for a second or two
8. The screen goes black.
9. The machine appears to go to sleep.  I know this as I have a voltage indicator on the PSU which tells me it drops from 12.01v to 4.97v as soon as the screen goes black

Can anyone help with this as I am desperate to get this working as I have a tight deadline to meet!  Any help is appreciated!

Thank you :)

Simon.